# Chemical element symbols task

Tags: python, string

I have to make a task where we need to check if a symbol is a valid symbol (by the rules of the task)

The background information of the task which I probably won't be able to explain:

[image]

Example provided by the assignment:

[image]

```
def isvalid(symbol, element, length = None):
    elbool = False
    
    if symbol[0]!=symbol[0].upper():
        return False #first letter in the symbol has to be a capital letter
    
        
    for i in range(len(symbol)-1):
            
        if element.find(symbol[i+1])>element.find(symbol[i]): #checking if the order is correct
            elbool = True
        else:
            return False
    
    if length is not None:
        if len(symbol)!=length:
            return False
        else:
            elbool = True
           
        
    return elbool
```

Is my code now but it doesn't work for example with this one: isvalid('Rcm', 'Americium') because there is an m before the c and it counts that one.

So I think I need to split the element string from the last letter in the symbol so I don't have that problem but how do I do that?

Sorry if the question is a bit confusing.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: maybe you should use `find(..., start_position)` to search after previous char.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the regular expressions module?  this is one case where it would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.find(needle, start_pos)` to look for the character *after* a certain location in `element`. Also, you don't need to mess with indices and keep finding the previous *and* current character from `symbol`. Just keep track of the location of the current character for the next iteration.

You should also do a case-insensitive search, because, using your example, there is no `"R"` in `"Americium"`. I do this by converting `element` to lowercase once, and then doing `.find(c.lower(), ...)` on each character in `symbol`

Finally, you forgot to check that all characters other than the first one in `symbol` are lowercase. I also added that to the for loop.

```
element = element.lower() # Lowercase element so that we can find characters correctly
lastfound = 0
for ix, c in enumerate(symbol):
    if ix > 0 and c.isupper():
        # Not the first character, and is uppercase
        return False

    thisfound = element.find(c.lower(), lastfound) # Find the location of this character
    if thisfound == -1: # character not found in element after location lastfound
        return False

    lastfound = thisfound # Set lastfound for the next iteration
```

A few other minor suggestions:

- You can `return False` as soon as you find something wrong. Then, at the end of the function, just `return True` because the only way you reach the end is when nothing is wrong.
- You can check if a character is lowercase with `symbol[0].islower()`. No need to do `symbol[0] != symbol[0].upper()`.
- You should check for the length requirement before you check for the order of characters, because that's the simpler check.

Applying all these:

```
def isvalid(symbol, element, length = None):
    if symbol[0].islower():
        return False

    if length is not None and len(symbol) != length:
        return False
    
    element = element.lower() # Lowercase element so that we can find characters correctly
    lastfound = 0
    for ix, c in enumerate(symbol):
        if ix > 0 and c.isupper():
            return False
        thisfound = element.find(c.lower(), lastfound) # Find the location of this character
        if thisfound == -1: # character not found in element after location lastfound
            return False

        lastfound = thisfound # Set lastfound for the next iteration
  
    return True
```

Using your tests:

```
>> isvalid('Zer', 'Zeddemorium')
True

>> isvalid('Zer', 'Zeddemorium', 2)
False

>> isvalid('di', 'Zeddemorium')
False

>> isvalid('Rcm', 'Americium')
True
```

Comment: Thank you so much, was breaking my head over this the whole afternoon!